# How to concat one million binary file in one binary file?

Tags: cygwin

I am trying to concat 1000000 binary files, I use Cygwin in order to put this command:

```
$ cat *.bin> All_Traces.bin
```

But the error that I find is:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This command works for 100000 files but it gives me this error for one million files. 
How to resolve this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this solution:

```
$ ls | sort --field-separator = --key 2 -h | xargs -rn 10 cat > All_Traces.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line is too long so you need to use xargs to pass 
all the file names to cat in manageable chunks.

```
ls *.bin |xargs cat   >> /tmp/All.bins
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please see the edited question.

Comment: It gives me an empty file

Comment: how big should be the final file ?

Comment: It is  32 Kb*1000000files